# SQL deadlock while attempting IX lock on page

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

[image]

I can't understand why this deadlock is occuring.
The transaction on the right affects (updates) only one row, it looks like so:

```
update table1
set column1 = 'value1'
where key1 = 1
```

I assume the IX request is for the page where the row (that is being updated) is located, right? But that cannot be, because there's a shared lock on this page. Or is the IX request for some other page?

Also is it possible to prevent the IX lock (maybe some hint)? Because I know that I'm updating only ONE row and there's no intent to update anything else in this transaction.

**UPDATED:**

Table1 - consists of five columns (renamed) and a primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [Key1] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Column1] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Column2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Column3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Column4] [int] NOT NULL,
    constraint PK_Key1 primary key([Key1])
)
```

The other transaction consists of one single select statement that contains a lot of joined tables, inluding Table1 - for security reasons I cannot divulge it here.

Comment: DDL for the table (including indexes) and the select query would be helpful.

Comment: What does the *other* transaction do?

Comment: For security reasons I can't answer your question -- maybe you could, at least, try to distill the other query down to exactly what it does with `column1` and `key1`? Your `UPDATE` may not be the problem -- even if it locks the correct row and nothing else, if the other query needs to touch everything, that still won't help. You cannot (in general) diagnose a deadlock just by looking at one involved party.

Comment: How much lock contention are we talking about here?  Could you set the [deadlock priority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186736.aspx) on this update query to low to make it always be the vicitm, and simply re-run it when a deadlock occurs?  Can your other process use HOLDLOCK or SERIALIZABLE?

Answer (score 1):

There is a ROWLOCK hint. E.g.:

```
update table1 with (ROWLOCK)
set column1 = 'value1'
where key1 = 1
```

Comment: I tried - with(rowlock) causes MS Sql to put the intent lock (IX) on the page as well...
I'm looking for ways to prevent IX, as a possible solution to this deadlock problem.

Comment: Looks like it is ignoring the hint. If you want to completely avoid locking at all, setting the transaction isolation level to snapshot may work: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT